# SSL handshake_failure in Client Hello

Tags: java, ssl

I'm using Java (12.0.2) to calla some REST Api, via ssl.
If i call the URL using CURL (specifying certificate and CA_root) everything is fine.
If i use the same endpoint in Java i get this SSL Client Hello

```
"ClientHello": {
  "client version"      : "TLSv1.2",
  "random"              : "15 AA 0C B1 62 A6 83 26 1E C3 B6 C3 8D D0 F9 19 DA F7 5A 9D 8B 08 0B 5C ED 96 A6 A7 CF 5A 67 C2",
  "session id"          : "",
  "cipher suites"       : "[TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384(0x009D), TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384(0x009F), TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256(0xCCAA), TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384(0x00A3), TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256(0x009C), TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256(0x009E), TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256(0x00A2), TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256(0x003D), TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256(0x006B), TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256(0x006A), TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA(0x0035), TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA(0x0039), TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA(0x0038), TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256(0x003C), TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256(0x0067), TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256(0x0040), TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA(0x002F), TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA(0x0033), TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA(0x0032), TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV(0x00FF)]",
  "compression methods" : "00",
  "extensions"          : [
    "status_request (5)": {
      "certificate status type": ocsp
      "OCSP status request": {
        "responder_id": <empty>
        "request extensions": {
          <empty>
        }
      }
    },
    "supported_groups (10)": {
      "versions": [ffdhe2048, ffdhe3072, ffdhe4096, ffdhe6144, ffdhe8192]
    },
    "signature_algorithms (13)": {
      "signature schemes": [ecdsa_secp256r1_sha256, ecdsa_secp384r1_sha384, ecdsa_secp521r1_sha512, rsa_pss_rsae_sha256, rsa_pss_rsae_sha384, rsa_pss_rsae_sha512, rsa_pss_pss_sha256, rsa_pss_pss_sha384, rsa_pss_pss_sha512, rsa_pkcs1_sha256, rsa_pkcs1_sha384, rsa_pkcs1_sha512, dsa_sha256, ecdsa_sha224, rsa_sha224, dsa_sha224, ecdsa_sha1, rsa_pkcs1_sha1, dsa_sha1]
    },
    "signature_algorithms_cert (50)": {
      "signature schemes": [ecdsa_secp256r1_sha256, ecdsa_secp384r1_sha384, ecdsa_secp521r1_sha512, rsa_pss_rsae_sha256, rsa_pss_rsae_sha384, rsa_pss_rsae_sha512, rsa_pss_pss_sha256, rsa_pss_pss_sha384, rsa_pss_pss_sha512, rsa_pkcs1_sha256, rsa_pkcs1_sha384, rsa_pkcs1_sha512, dsa_sha256, ecdsa_sha224, rsa_sha224, dsa_sha224, ecdsa_sha1, rsa_pkcs1_sha1, dsa_sha1]
    },
    "status_request_v2 (17)": {
      "cert status request": {
        "certificate status type": ocsp_multi
        "OCSP status request": {
          "responder_id": <empty>
          "request extensions": {
            <empty>
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "extended_master_secret (23)": {
      <empty>
    },
    "supported_versions (43)": {
      "versions": [TLSv1.2]
    }
  ]
}
```

And then the server responds with

```
"Alert": {
  "level"      : "fatal",
  "description": "handshake_failure"
}
```

I have to point that when connecting with Curl, the Server accept this Cipher TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 that is not in the offered cipher list in the SSL exchange.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Found the issue. In A property file configuration i had this line

```
system.com.sun.net.ssl.enableECC=false
```

That was preventing the usage of some Chyper set.